# Using MarkupBuilder with Groovy... problem creating XML parameters

Tags: java, xml, groovy

I have the following Groovy code but it wont work:

```
xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder() 
xmldata = xml.Plugins(nextid: '10') {
   Target(name: 'default.auth') {
     Port(protocol: 'https') {
       8080
     }
   }
}
println xmldata
```

I want it to result in:

```
<Plugins nextid='10'>
  <Target name='default.auth'>
    <Port protocol='https'>8080</Port>
  </Target>
</Plugins>
```

What I am actually getting is this:

```
<Plugins nextid='10'>
  <Target name='default.auth'>
    <Port protocol='https' />
  </Target>
</Plugins>
```

Can anyone provide some insight on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `mkp.yield` to make it output the `8080` value to the xml, like so:

```
xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder() 
xmldata = xml.Plugins(nextid: '10') {
   Target(name: 'default.auth') {
     Port(protocol: 'https') {
       mkp.yield 8080
     }
   }
}
```